# Вывести содержимое координат и hintContent из JSON-массива видимых меток на Яндекс.Картах

Tags: yandex-maps-api, dom

Есть:

1. Массив меток, с координатами и заголовками
2. JS отдающий из массива #1 список id меток, отображаемых на заданном куске карты
   (в consloe.log)

   http://jsfiddle.net/Benadiy/pzrv6s83/

Вопрос:

Как отобразить во втором div'e (`#bombom`) значения координат и `hintContent`'a из отображаемых в данный момент на карте?
Cписок видимых id на карте получаем:

```
myMap.events.add(['boundschange','datachange','objecttypeschange'], function(e){...
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Benadiy/pzrv6s83/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/pzrv6s83/11/

```
myMap.events.add(['boundschange','datachange','objecttypeschange'], function(e){
    bombom.innerHTML = '';
    objectManager.objects.each(function (object) {
        var objectState = objectManager.getObjectState(object.id);
        if (objectState.isShown) {
            var o = objectManager.objects.getById(object.id);
            bombom.innerHTML += o.geometry.coordinates + ' ' + o.properties.hintContent + '<br>'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Денис,а как вывести список этих свойств (координаты + подсказка) при первой загрузке страницы, а не только тогда, когда происходит изменение карты?

Comment: Создайте отдельную функцию, которая из objectManager-а достает объекты и данные их, собственно, то что находится внутри событий ['boundschange','datachange','objecttypeschange'] сейчас. И вызывайте ее после создания objectManager и при событиях, выше указанных

Comment: Денис, спасибо! Нужную функцию скопипастил в загрузку данных из JSON'a - вот так - http://jsfiddle.net/Benadiy/tmofgL7a/ и все получилось!